# Is there a section in this website for right to left written languages? Like Persian?

Tags: discussion

this website is so useful , but so far , it only has interface with users who type in English , it could be great if there was a section that could deal with the users of these languages , since I know that it's a bit more tricky to work on latex in these languages, but here could be the best place to get the feedback from the users

Comment: There are quite a lot messages on site concerning RTL, persian and arabic scripts as well as hebrew, CJK, greek, cyrillic, sanskrit. I don't know about mayan,  but it is likely that we have one question about scripts people deal with in their daily life. You can sort by tags around here to get matching questions, try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persian

Comment: There might be something else of interest: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/ which could be more to the question at hand, i am not sure if i understood the question correctly.

Comment: you are right @Johannes_B thank you , I didn't search it first , well the blog was interesting , enough comments to conclude no need to discuss

Comment: As there is also project `xepersian`, there might be some mailing list or specialised forum. Problem is, i cannot speak/read persian, so i cannot really tell.

Answer (score 12):

You **can** ask questions **about** any particular language, including Persian, other RTL languages, CJK etc.

What you **cannot** do is to ask your question **in** Persian. The only official language of this website is English.

The tag we use is [right-to-left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/right-to-left), which can be accompanied by [persian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persian), [arabic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic) or [hebrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew) (for the three most common RTL languages).

Comment: “What you cannot do is to ask your question in Persian.”  I seem to remember a meta discussion on some other SE site coming to the consensus that it was fine to give questions/answers in other languages, so long as an English translation was included as well.  Could that be a reasonable policy here?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine You can see [this related meta.tex discussion](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687/non-english-questions), which made our policy clear. You can open the topic again, I won't be against opening the topic again, but my personal opinion is unchanged, for all the reasons listed in the linked discussion.